# System Center Service Management Automation (SMA) PowerShell Runbook Invoke-NcSsh : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: powershell, automation, runbook, netapp

Tried to run a powershell script inside System Center Service Management Automation (SMA) to query some informations from NetApp. The following command was used:

```
Invoke-NcSsh -Command "node run -node $Node sysconfig -a"
```

I was able to run the command successfully directly inside the PowerShell ISE on the runbook workers (NetApp_PowerShell_Toolkit_9.6.0 and putty-64bit-0.73 installed). But as soon as I was running the runbook as a SMA job it failed with the following error:

> Invoke-NcSsh : The system cannot find the file specified
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-NcSsh], Win32Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,DataONTAP.C.PowerShell.SDK.Cmdlets.Toolkit.Ssh.InvokeNcSsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

procmon.exe was showing that Orchestrator.Sandbox.exe was looking for the plink.exe (from putty used for sending ssh command) inside the following folders:
[image]

Solution:
Copy plink.exe to one of this folders.